# Cloth Deform when animated

Tags: animation, blender, cloth-simulation

I am using blender 2.77. I wanna ask why is the upper part of my cloth is flying upwards instead of dropping down when animated? And it is also slightly deform as well when animated. But the bottom part of it is work just fine...I had tried different setting, like adjusting the gravity, self collision distance, material mass, steps, cloth collision setting and it still do not solve the problem...Anyone can give me a solution regarding this problem? thank you :)

here is the link of the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHIFT.jpg [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHIFT.jpg)